# How to change language FirebaseUI- Web with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, vue.js, firebaseui

I would like to change the language of my firebaseUI, using Vue.js.
I still haven't come up with a solution
Below is the code where I call FirebaseUI

```
 if (process.browser) {
      const firebaseui = require('firebaseui')

      console.log(firebaseui)

      const ui =
        firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance() || new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(auth)

      const config = {
        credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE,
        signInOptions: [
          authProviders.Google,
          authProviders.Email,
          authProviders.Facebook
        ],
        signInFlow: 'popup',
        tosUrl: '/tos',
        privacyPolicyUrl: '/privacy-policy',
        callbacks: {
          signInSuccessWithAuthResult: this.signInResult
        }
      }
      ui.disableAutoSignIn()

      if (this.$store.state.userNfc) {
        this.openAppPage()
      } else {
        ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', config)
      }
    }
  },
```